# What is the difference between @param and: param in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, docstring

I want to document a class, and I have seen that in PyCharm when a docstring is added automatically it adds

```
:param param_name1: 
:param param_name2:
```

However, I have seen that some people use

```
@param param_name1:
@param param_name2:
```

I wonder which of both is valid, and which one is the one that a Pythonista should house.

I also wonder if I should include the `@type` or `:type` for describing the data type of a parameter.

```
"""
:type rating: int
:param rating: hotel rating
"""
```

This is the way I am writing my docstring. So, is it okay or is there a much better way or stand way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/using-docstrings-to-specify-types.html#d331661e129

```
:param param_name1: 
:param param_name2:
```

is reStructuredText format instead of

```
@param param_name1:
@param param_name2:
```

is Epitext format

Epitext format can be enabled with File > Settings > Python Integrated Tools and set "Docstring format" to "Epytext"

Comment: should I include the :type or is it optional? I would like to have the best practices in my code.

Comment: I think you should, yes